# How to create automatic update for c# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looking for automatic update for my c# windows application.
can somebody help me that where can i find the open source auto update project or how can i create it by c#.

Thanks all

Comment: I think the OP means the application itself. Something like Fiddler does - it starts up, and if there is a newer version it prompts the user to update.

Answer (score 7):

[ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/748fh114.aspx) would do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

There are frameworks which u can integrate to ur application. ClickOnce will be one of the option but you need you assemblies signed.

here are the free libraries which provides automatic updates

http://autoupdatemodule.codeplex.com/

http://autoupdater.codeplex.com

http://brice-lambson.blogspot.in/2011/03/automatic-update-for-codeplex-projects.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

What you probably need is to have two "applications" - one which will be started by the user, and when it happens it will check some place (website?) for updates; if such updates exist it will install it (or prompt for doing so). If not, it will launch the "real" application.

There are some technologies to help you do that, such as Click Once, you can check them out.